# Auto-progress input field deletes '0's in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've built a system for a user to input credit card numbers, bank code numbers, two-step codes etc. The small jQuery script that controls the auto-progression when the maxlength is reached seems to work well on most devices and browsers, with the exception of Firefox (45.0.2, untested on other FF's).

With Firefox, it automatically deletes any '0' that's entered, which is a real problem. Admittedly I'm not the strongest jquery scripter out there, however I can't work out what it is in my code that triggers this behaviour.

I've set up a codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWxYag

Using my script (as derived from several SO threads):

```
var $single_degit = $('input.singleDigit');
        $single_degit.keyup(function (e) {
            var $elm = $(this);
            if (e.which == 8) {
            //backspace
                $elm.prevAll($single_degit).first().focus();
        } else if ((e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 96 && e.which < 106)) {
            $elm.next($single_degit).focus();
        } else {
            $elm.val('');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Have I somehow written this behaviour in? Or am I experiencing a bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
else if ((e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 96 && e.which < 106))
```

Your code should read:

```
else if ((e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 95 && e.which < 106))
```

As the numeric keypad 0 (which I assume is the zero you're talking about) uses keycode 96, which is not included in your statement. You've accounted for normal 0 (keycode 48), but not 96.

An updated codepen is below which will work better cross platform, as platforms implementing features such as spellcheck will return keycode 0 or 229, not the code you're after.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZMmQN

Comment: Sorry to pick your brain further @Nasapc123, but can you see an issue with the script that would completely prevent an android browser from entering numbers? I'm wondering if the keyboard mapping doesn't match the soft keyboards?

Comment: I'e edited my answer to include an updated codepen. This works cross-platform as you're running into issues with only keycode 0 or 229 returning, and should handle events such as a user pasting into the field, which wouldn't have been filtered previously.

Comment: If I could buy you a beer, I would. Thank you for that, it's stopped me pulling my hair out like I have been most of the morning!